# Creating morphed component with Laravel Filament

Tags: laravel, database, backend, laravel-filament

I have a GPU model.

```
class GPU extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'gpu';

    protected $fillable = ['memory'];


    public function component(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Component::class, 'productable');
    }
}
```

So, this is like this because when I create a GPU, I also create a component with attributes. It works thru Postman, but now I am implementing Laravel Filament and it doesn't seem to work. The GPU is created, but the component stays empty. So, GPU has its attribute memory that differs it from the component- I have more components like CPU, PSU and ETC. so MorphOne is perfect for this.

```
class Component extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    protected $table = 'component';

    protected $fillable = ['productable_id', 'productable_type', 'manufacturer_id', 'model',  'price', 'description', 'discount', 'product_type_cro'];


    public function productable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

    public function manufacturer(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Manufacturer::class, 'manufacturer_id');
    }

    public function images(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ComponentImage::class);
    }
}
```

I am using MorhpOne to achieve what I want, but how can I do this in Filament Resource? I currently have this in Filament GPU resource:

```
    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('model')->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('memory')->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('price')->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('manufacturer_id')->required(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('description'),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('discount'),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('productable_id'),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('productable_type'),


            ]);
    }
```

This is what the DB looks like when I create GPU thru Postman:

[image]

This is in the component table, and this in GPU table:

[image]

This is store method in GPU Filament resource:

```
    public static function store(Request $request)
    {
        $gpu = GPU::create($request->validated());

        $component = Component::create([
            'model' => $request->model,
            'price' => $request->price,
            'manufacturer_id' => $request->manufacturer_id,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'productable_id' => $gpu->id,
            'productable_type' => GPU::class,
            'discount' => $request->discount,
            'product_type_cro' => "Grafička kartica",
        ]);

        $gpu->component()->save($component);

        return redirect()->route('gpu.index')->with('success', 'GPU created successfully');
    }
```

I want to achieve the same behaviour thru Filament. Currently only GPU is created and component tables stays empty. What should I change? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For polymorphic relations, Especially for `morphOne`, you can use [this part of the document](https://filamentphp.com/docs/3.x/panels/resources/relation-managers#layout-form-components---saving-form-fields-to-a-single-relationship). Filament describes best practices for each relation type in the link I provided. You can search for any relationship type and discover the best way to handle it.

Here's an example of the solution.

```php
public static function form(Form $form): Form
{
    return $form
        ->schema([
            Forms\Components\TextInput::make('memory')->required(),
            Fieldset::make('Component')
                ->relationship('component')
                ->schema([
                    TextInput::make('model'),
                    TextInput::make('price')->numeric(),
                    TextInput::make('discount')->numeric(),
                    TextInput::make('description'),
                    TextInput::make('product_type_cro')
                ])
        ]);
}
```

We can make a Fieldset to separate the component data section in the above code. As the document mentions, you can use other things like Grid, ...

Then, we set a relationship for that Fieldset, which must be the relationship's name in the resource's model.

With this solution, I don't see any purpose in changing the default behaviour of the store method, and you can leave it to Filament.